# Github Graphql API create repo

Tags: graphql, github-api-v4

I am using below query to create repo:

```
   gh api -i graphql -f query='
   mutation {
   createRepository(input: {name: "gh-create-test", visibility: PRIVATE, ownerId: "ID"}) {
    repository {
      url
    }
  }
}
'
```

THe repo gets created successfully but without admin rights whereas when I create repo from GITHUB UI the repo has admin rights. Can anyone please help what's the issue in this query?

Comment: what do you mean by admin right

Comment: By admin rights I mean , I don’t see the settings tab for the repo which is created by graphql api but same is visible when created via gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created one, Make sure you are getting the id first and pass it to the createRepository

```
query{
  repositoryOwner(login:"yourLoginId"){
    id
    login
    repositories(first:1) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and create a repository by passing the ownerid

```
mutation {
   createRepository(input: {name: "gh-create-test", visibility: PRIVATE, ownerId: "idobtainedabove"}) {
    repository {
      url
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: “yourloginid” what Id is expected here? Github login ?

Comment: Error:       ```                                                                                                                                              {
  "data": {
    "createRepository": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "type": "FORBIDDEN",
      "path": [
        "createRepository"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "saml_failure": false
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "message": "Resource not accessible by integration"
    ```

Comment: But i can create repos from GUI with proper permissions why this is not working with cli?

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you trying to do this within an organization?

Comment: Yes I am trying for an org

Comment: Do I need to define my PATanywhere?

Comment: No need to define

Comment: I exported PAT: export GITHUB_TOKEN="MyPAT" and get below error:                                               "errors": [
    {
      "type": "NOT_FOUND",
      "path": [
        "createRepository"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 4
        }
      ],
      "message": "Could not resolve to RepositoryOwner node with the global id of "nodeid"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235643/discussion-between-stack-iq-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: It worked finally after enabling SSO. Thanks for your time..:)

Comment: There are two obligatory fields to create a repo: `name` and `visibility`. Regarding visibility, case matters. However `ownerId` is not mandatory because of missing `!` in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/input-objects#createrepositoryinput)